# Collision betwen useState interdependency and useEffect in React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a `useEffect` with dependency A and a function where something will trigger if B is true, looking like this:

```
const [docs, setDocs] = useState(null);
const [update, setUpdate] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
  if (update == true) {
    // do this
  }
}, [docs]);
```

In another function, i'm setting `update` to true, and I update `docs`.

```
const deleteDocument = (a) => {    
  const newArray = a;
  setUpdate(true);
  setDocs(newArray);

};
```

The problem is that the `useEffect` will trigger before `update` is actually updated, therefore not executing the inner function.

Since I would like to do this the proper way (not adding a timeout), what would be the standard way of dealing with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is

```
  setUpdate(true);
  setDocs(newArray);
```

Setting a state is an async function, where you cannot wait till `update` is set before next state change occurs.

#### useRef (one of many solutions)

```
const docs = useRef();
const [update, setUpdate] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
  if (update == true) {
    // do this
  // use can use "docs" here as "docs.current"
  }
}, [update]);


const deleteDocument = (a) => {    
  const newArray = a;
// set the new value of Docs. Changing 'ref' doesnot trigger a render
  docs.current = newArray;
  setUpdate(true);
};
```

And you can either create `update` to `useRef` or `docs` to `useRef`. Anything should work

Answer (score 0):

If you need `update` to be updated, that means that your `useEffect` depends on `update` also. So you should add `update` as a dependency in the dependency array.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  if (update == true) {
    // do this
  }
}, [update, docs]);
```

Setting states (`setState`) is an asynchronous function so you can't rely that one will be executed before or after another.